# For loops in postgresql doesnt run on function, but can run outside function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Some one please help me on this problem. I'm using postgresql ver 12. Thank you. Please read the comment on the result. Running from function doesn't work. so weird.

-- NOT WORKING

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mefunc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
a RECORD;
BEGIN

    FOR a IN SELECT "aa" FROM medata LOOP
        INSERT INTO othermedata ("id", "aa") VALUES ('1', a.aa);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

when i raise notice the value of a i get ()

WORKING

```
DO $$
DECLARE
a RECORD;
BEGIN

    FOR a IN SELECT "aa" FROM medata LOOP
        INSERT INTO othermedata ("id", "aa") VALUES ('1', a.aa);
    END LOOP;

END $$
```

When I raise notice the value of `a` I get output as "someoutputdata"

Comment: What is `i`? Can you show the code with the `RAISE` and the result?

Comment: Im referring to ME. sorry.

Comment: you don't need a loop for that to begin with

Comment: I also don't understand the purpose of the trigger. Each time the trigger fires you are copying **all** rows from `medata` to `othermedata`. In a trigger I would have expected some kind of condition based on the row that fired the trigger.

Comment: Actually I am just simplifying the codes here. I need the loop because the statement going to return more than 1 row.

Comment: If the function return VOID, result still the same

Comment: I'm not, completely copy all the medata data into othermedata. As you can see I'm inserting a value for id which not from medata table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You should return new record when using Trigger. As you are not returning any value so it is returning null value. I have tested the below code and it is working fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mefunc()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
a RECORD;
BEGIN

    FOR a IN SELECT aa FROM metadata loop
        INSERT INTO othermedata (id, aa) VALUES ('1', a.aa);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN new;
END
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```